# how to make a function blocking in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, server, blocking

I'm writing a server-client program, and here is a simplified face of my code :

```
public static void main (String[] args){

       function1();
       System.out.println(object1.getField1());
}
```

client class :

```
class client {
public function1(){
//connecting to server and writing the field value to dataOutoutStream
}
```

serverClass :

```
class Server{
    //accepting client and reading the value from dataInputStream
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           object1.setField1(//something);
        }
    }
    }).start();
}
```

somewhere in function1, I connect the server and it runs a thread which changes field1 of object1.

but the problem is that before the field has actually changed, it prints the previous value.
how can I make function1 blocking so that I can prevent this problem?

Comment: You'll need some kind of coordination with that thread. We can't help you any further without seeing what it does/how.

Comment: I suggest reading through all of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ if possible. It has really good advice.

Comment: you may try to use Observer pattern here https://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tried to bring a simplified view of my code

Comment: You can integrate some kind of `CountDownLatch` or `CompletableFuture` in the server and expose it as a return value from `function1`.

Comment: thanks everyone for help :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the `function1()` seems to be spawning a new thread to perform the long running task. But it does not wait for it to finish. Consequently, the caller, which is your `main()` method, does not see the changed value of `getField1()`.

you have to ,

1. get the `Future` or a handle on that long running task so that you can choose to block or wait on it.
2. modify the function1() to return the Future
3. wait on the Future

```java
private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

private Future<?> function1() {
        return executorService.submit(() -> {
            // your long running task which updates **field1**
        });
}

public static void main (String[] args){
       Future<?> resultFuture = function1();
       // wait on this future , i.e. block
       resultFuture.get();
       System.out.println(object1.getField1());
}
```